# After exceeding 24 characters strncat or strndmp adds random characters

Tags: c, string, char

I'm currently learning C and I decided to make a simple function which swaps the two halves of a string. I used strndmp to get one half of the string and used strncat to add the other half to the end of the strndmp result. After this I printed the output. The script outputted the string with its halves swapped but with the last few characters replaced with random characters. I'm really confused since this doesn't happen if I print something before printing the swapped string or if the inputted string is under 24 characters. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void halfSwap(char * sample);
void halfSwap(char * sample){
    char * buff;
    buff = strndup(sample+strlen(sample)/2,strlen(sample));
    strncat(buff,sample,strlen(sample)/2);
    printf("Sample length: %d\n",strlen(sample));
    printf("Buffer output: %s\n",buff);
}
int main() {
    //printf("Uncommenting this will remove the error\n\n");
    //Characters only go missing after sample exceeds 24 chars
    halfSwap(" worrrrrrrlddhellllllllooo");
    //Error does not occur after printng once
    halfSwap(" worrrrrrrlddhellllllllooo");
}
```

And the output is:

```
Sample length: 26
Buffer output: hellllllllooo worrrrrrrl
Sample length: 26
Buffer output: hellllllllooo worrrrrrrldd
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're leaking memory in `halfSwap()` each time you call it.

Comment: AFAICS, the specification of [`strndup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html) does not guarantee to allocate as much memory as the second argument.  If the input is shorter than the second argument, it may only allocate enough space for the input, including the null terminator.  Therefore, appending to the allocated space is undefined behaviour.  If you're on a platform where you can run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), use it.

Comment: You'll probably get the answer on your own if you help yourself by debugging the code (via *code-blocks* for example). In addition, debugging and inspecting the values of variables & pointers will help you learn faster.

Comment: `strndup` is not allocating the required `strlen(sample)+1` characters you need.  It is only allocating up to and including the terminating null charcter, starting from the middle of the string, i.e. half as much memory as you're actually using.  Once you write past what you've allocated, anything can happen.

Comment: I think this question will not be closed. So would any of you like to make an answer? At least two of the comments seem to answer sufficiently, and I would appreciate getting this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to strndup only allocates enough memory the the latter half of the string, so when you strncat to it, it goes beyond the space allocated for buff, and the behavior is undefined.  What you probably want instead us something along these lines:

```
int len = strlen(sample);
int half = len / 2;
buff = (char*)malloc(len+1);
strcpy(buff,&sample[half]);
strncat(buff,sample,half);
```